# ESD Protection on serial relay switches

Tags: relay, protection, esd

I'm trying to switch high-quality audio signals using 2 serial relays like the picture below.

[image]
I'm not sure if this is the best solution to switch between 2 inputs and 2 outputs, but here it is.
In this case, I'm sure ESD protection is a must. So I'm trying to place fewest TVS diodes at the best location.
I thought it would be the best to place it in between 2 relays because regardless of the input/output selected, it will go through the middle.
is my thinking on the right track? Do I just have to find the right Diodes now?
Any comments or suggestions are welcome on any part of my thought.

Comment: It's unlikely that the relays need ESD protection so what are you trying to achieve by using ESD diodes?

Comment: I think the RELAY_SWITCH_Lx pins need ESD protection more than pins 3 and 6.

Comment: @Andyaka I will be turning off all the signal lines when I use the switch, but I'm worried that some voltages might not get fully discharged and strikes ESD when the switch happens. Just like a simple load switch.

Comment: @bobuhito It's not showned in the picture, but I'm using [ULN2003](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ulq2003a.pdf?ts=1591056919648) Should this be ok? I actually have never used the ULN2003

Comment: @BrianH OK, nevermind, ULN2003 should have ESD protection already on the pins.